# good order for deallocating in ecpg

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, ecpg

In a pgc code, I do a kind of:

```
exec sql begin work;
exec sql prepare my_rqt from :rqt_insert  ;   
exec sql execute my_rqt using :foo, :bar ;
if ( sqlca.sqlcode == 0 ){
    exec sql deallocate prepare my_rqt ;
    exec sql commit ;
} else {
    exec sql deallocate prepare my_rqt ;
    exec sql rollback ;
}
```

when *insert* works, everything is fine, but, in the othercase, I get an error on the 'deallocate' statement :

> sqlca.sqlstate : 26000 : invalid statement "my_rqt" on line xx

If I do *deallocate* after *rollback*, I don't get this message.
I can't find any sample code of this in any documentation.

Thanks for any help on the right order to do such things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get an error, the transaction is aborted and you cannot do anything before you roll back.